# Oracle identify if a delete will cascade

Tags: oracle, cascade

I am working on a legacy oracle database system (10g) and I do not have detailed schema information. I need to find out if deleting a particular record in a table will cause cascading deletes in other tables. I have checked for triggers. But, I am not sure about cascading due to referential constraints. Is there a simple way to identify this?

Comment: i guess i'm getting old - 10g is legacy now ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you know (or can determine) the foreign key constraint(s) involved, you can look at the `DELETE_RULE` column from `DBA_CONSTRAINTS`

```
SELECT constraint_name, delete_rule
  FROM dba_constraints
 WHERE r_constraint_name = <<name of the primary key constraint>>
   AND r_owner = <<owner of the primary key constraint>>
   AND delete_rule = 'CASCADE'
```

will show you all the foreign key constraints that refer to a particular primary key constraint and will cascade the deletes.  If you care about constraints that will do a `SET NULL` when the parent row is deleted, you could look for rows where the `delete_rule` was `SET NULL` as well.

Note that if you do not have privileges on the `DBA_CONSTRAINTS` table, you can use `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` instead assuming that you're really only concerned with tables that you have `SELECT` privileges on.

Comment: Why not use ```user_constraints``` view?

Comment: @Ben - You certainly could use `user_constraints` or `all_constraints` if you know that you own any constraints or that you have access to any tables where those constraints exist.  It is possible, though probably unlikely, that there is a table in a different schema that you don't have `select` access to that has a foreign key that references a table in your schema.  In that case, you'd need to use `dba_constraints`.

Comment: We have customer systems and not DBA privileges (and we don't want them anyway). So we design everything within the same schema and we can always rely on the user-views. IMHO relying on ```dba_constraints``` is just if you are sure to have the privileges and you should have them or at best be a DBA in general :) I guess ```all_constraints``` would work as well, but could be problematic if you have grants to another schema.

Comment: @Ben - It's not just DBA's that have access to the `dba_*` views.  It is often pretty reasonable for read-only developer users to have the `select any dictionary` privilege or at least to have grants on the specific `dba_*` views that they need.

Comment: Sure… except if you have to take data security into account like banking :)

Comment: @Ben - `select any dictionary` doesn't give you access to any data.  It just lets you know that a particular table exists or that it has a particular column.  It doesn't let you view the data in that table.  Plenty of banks are happy to let developers confirm that there is a `social_security_num` column in the `customer` table in production so long as they can't view the data in that column.

Comment: Ah… sorry, my mistake. I mistook it for ```select any table``` :)